# Python Tkinter: Progress bar malfunction when using multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, canvas, tkinter, progress-bar

Please run the following example.

I have created a progress bar for my application, and by pressing the "Open" button a progress bar pops up. However, the progress bar does not fill up and it appears that the script is halt at

```
bar.set(i)
```

when function ProgressBarLoop is called.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH, Label, Toplevel, Canvas, Button
import thread
import time

class ProgressBar:
   def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
      master = Toplevel(parent)
      master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.hide )
      self.master = master
      self.master.overrideredirect(True)
      ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
      hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
      w = (True and ws*0.2) or 0.2
      h = (True and ws*0.15) or 0.15
      x = (ws/2) - (w/2) 
      y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
      self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height * 2.5, x, y))

      self.mode = 'percent'
      self.ONOFF = 'on'
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.frame = None
      self.canvas = None
      self.progressBar = None
      self.backgroundBar = None
      self.progressformat = 'percent'
      self.label = None
      self.progress = 0

      self.createWidget()
      self.frame.pack()
      self.set(0.0)                  # initialize to 0%
   def createWidget(self):
      self.frame = Frame(self.master, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'sunken')
      self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame)
      self.backgroundBar = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill = 'darkblue')
      self.progressBar = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill = 'blue')
      self.setWidth()
      self.setHeight()
      self.label = Label(self.frame, text = 'Loading...', width = 20)
      self.label.pack(side = 'top') # where text label should be packed
      self.canvas.pack()
   def setWidth(self, width = None):
      if width is not None:
         self.width = width
      self.canvas.configure(width = self.width)
      self.canvas.coords(self.backgroundBar, 0, 0, self.width, self.height)
      self.setBar() # update progress bar
   def setHeight(self, height = None):
      if height is not None:
         self.height = height
      self.canvas.configure(height = self.height)
      self.canvas.coords(self.backgroundBar, 0, 0, self.width, self.height)
      self.setBar() # update progress bar
   def set(self, value):
      if self.ONOFF == 'off': # no need to set and redraw if hidden
         return
      if self.mode == 'percent':
         self.progress = value
         self.setBar()
         return
   def setBar(self):
      self.canvas.coords(self.progressBar,0, 0, self.width * self.progress/100.0, self.height)
      self.canvas.update_idletasks()
   def hide(self):
      if isinstance(self.master, Toplevel):
         self.master.withdraw()
      else:
         self.frame.forget()
      self.ONOFF = 'off'
   def configure(self, **kw):
      mode = None
      for key,value in kw.items():
         if key=='mode':
            mode = value
         elif key=='progressformat':
            self.progressformat = value
      if mode:
         self.mode = mode
def ProgressBarLoop(window, bar):
   bar.configure(mode = 'percent', progressformat = 'ratio')
   while(True):
      if not window.loading:
         break
      for i in range(101):
         bar.set(i)
         print "refreshed bar"
         time.sleep(0.001)
   bar.hide()

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
      parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (100, 100, 0, 0))
      Button(parent, text = "Open", command = self.onOpen).pack()
   def onOpen(self, event = None):
      self.loading = True
      bar = ProgressBar(self, width=150, height=18)
      thread.start_new_thread(ProgressBarLoop, (self, bar))
      while(True):
         pass
root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

After trying dano's answer, it works but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/sdev/tools/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/mnt/sdev/tools/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/jun/eclipse/connScript/src/root/nested/test.py", line 88, in ProgressBarLoop
    bar.set(i)
  File "/home/jun/eclipse/connScript/src/root/nested/test.py", line 61, in set
    self.setBar()
  File "/home/jun/eclipse/connScript/src/root/nested/test.py", line 64, in setBar
    self.canvas.coords(self.progressBar,0, 0, self.width * self.progress/100.0, self.height)
  File "/mnt/sdev/tools/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2178, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args)))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're running an infinite loop immediately after you start the thread:

```
def onOpen(self, event = None):
   self.loading = True
   bar = ProgressBar(self, width=150, height=18)
   thread.start_new_thread(ProgressBarLoop, (self, bar))
   while(True):  # Infinite loop
      pass
```

Because of this, control never returns to the `Tk` event loop, so the progress bar can never be updated. The code should work fine if you remove the loop.

Also, you should use the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module instead of the `thread` module, as suggested in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html):

> Note The `thread` module has been renamed to `_thread` in Python 3. The
>   2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your
>   sources to Python 3; however, you should consider using the high-level
>   `threading` module instead.

Putting it altogether, here's what `onOpen` should look like:

```
def onOpen(self, event = None):
   self.loading = True
   bar = ProgressBar(self, width=150, height=18)
   t = threading.Thread(target=ProgressBarLoop, args=(self, bar))
   t.start()
```

**Edit:**

Trying to update tkinter widgets from multiple threads is somewhat finicky. When I tried this code on three different systems, I ended up getting three different results. Avoiding loops in the threaded method helped avoid any errors:

```
def ProgressBarLoop(window, bar, i=0):
    bar.configure(mode = 'percent', progressformat = 'ratio')
    if not window.loading:
        bar.hide()
        return
    bar.set(i)
    print "refreshed bar"
    i+=1
    if i == 101:
        # Reset the counter
        i = 0
    window.root.after(1, ProgressBarLoop, window, bar, i)
```

But really, if we're not using an infinite loop in `ProgressBarLoop` anyway, there's really no need to use a separate thread at all. This version of `ProgressBarLoop` can be called in the main thread, and the GUI won't be blocked for any noticeable amount of time.

Comment: Hmm, I get an error when I close the window RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Comment: @JamestheGreat Are you running the exact sample code you included above, except with my `onOpen` method? I haven't been able to reproduce that error. Using `Tk` with threads is somewhat tricky to do safely, but as long as your main thread is in `root.mainloop()`, it would have expected it to behave ok.

Comment: I am running on Python 2.7 and on Linux.

Comment: I pressed the "x" close button on the application to quit while the progress bar is running.

Comment: Please see the Edit version for the exact error msg

Comment: I think I know what happened. I changed .sleep(0.001) to .sleep(0.01), then error shows up. Why is that?

Comment: @JamestheGreat I've edited my answer. Trying to update a Tkinter GUI from outside of the main thread is hard to get right, and seems to behave differently depending on the versions of Python/Tcl/Tk and the platform you're running on. If possible, I would avoid using threads altogether, or at least avoid touching the GUI itself from outside the main thread.

Comment: I have created another question for the same example, but different problem. Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069567/python-tkinter-progress-bar-does-not-get-minimized-when-main-application-gets-m