# Python Tkinter: Progress bar does not get minimized when main application gets minimized

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

Please run the following example.

I have created a progress bar for my application, and by pressing the "Open" button a progress bar pops up. However, the progress bar does not get minimized when main application gets minimized.

I have tried the following line of code, but it only works if I comment out self.master.overrideredirect(True):

```
self.master.transient(parent)
```

Example (Python 2.7.3, Linux, Tkinter version $Revision: 81008 $):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH, Label, Toplevel, Canvas, Button
import threading

class ProgressBar:
   def __init__(self, parent, width, height):
      master = Toplevel(parent)
      master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.hide )
      self.master = master
      self.master.overrideredirect(True)
      ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
      hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
      w = (True and ws*0.2) or 0.2
      h = (True and ws*0.15) or 0.15
      x = (ws/2) - (w/2) 
      y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
      self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height * 2.5, x, y))

      self.mode = 'percent'
      self.ONOFF = 'on'
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.frame = None
      self.canvas = None
      self.progressBar = None
      self.backgroundBar = None
      self.progressformat = 'percent'
      self.label = None
      self.progress = 0

      self.createWidget()
      self.frame.pack()
      self.set(0.0)                  # initialize to 0%

      #self.master.transient(parent)
   def createWidget(self):
      self.frame = Frame(self.master, borderwidth = 1, relief = 'sunken')
      self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame)
      self.backgroundBar = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill = 'darkblue')
      self.progressBar = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height, fill = 'blue')
      self.setWidth()
      self.setHeight()
      self.label = Label(self.frame, text = 'Loading...', width = 20)
      self.label.pack(side = 'top') # where text label should be packed
      self.canvas.pack()
   def setWidth(self, width = None):
      if width is not None:
         self.width = width
      self.canvas.configure(width = self.width)
      self.canvas.coords(self.backgroundBar, 0, 0, self.width, self.height)
      self.setBar() # update progress bar
   def setHeight(self, height = None):
      if height is not None:
         self.height = height
      self.canvas.configure(height = self.height)
      self.canvas.coords(self.backgroundBar, 0, 0, self.width, self.height)
      self.setBar() # update progress bar
   def set(self, value):
      if self.ONOFF == 'off': # no need to set and redraw if hidden
         return
      if self.mode == 'percent':
         self.progress = value
         self.setBar()
         return
   def setBar(self):
      self.canvas.coords(self.progressBar,0, 0, self.width * self.progress/100.0, self.height)
      self.canvas.update_idletasks()
   def hide(self):
      if isinstance(self.master, Toplevel):
         self.master.withdraw()
      else:
         self.frame.forget()
      self.ONOFF = 'off'
   def configure(self, **kw):
      mode = None
      for key,value in kw.items():
         if key=='mode':
            mode = value
         elif key=='progressformat':
            self.progressformat = value
      if mode:
         self.mode = mode
def ProgressBarLoop(window, bar, i = 0, direction = "a"):
   bar.configure(mode = 'percent', progressformat = 'ratio')
   if not window.loading:
      bar.hide()
      return
   bar.set(i)
   if direction == "a":
      i += 1
   else:
      i -= 1
   if i == 101:
      direction = "d"
   elif i == 0 and direction == "d":
      direction = "a"
   window.parent.after(1, ProgressBarLoop, window, bar, i, direction)

class Application(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)
      parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (100, 100, 0, 0))
      Button(parent, text = "Open", command = self.onOpen).pack()
   def onOpen(self, event = None):
      self.loading = True
      bar = ProgressBar(self, width=150, height=18)
      t = threading.Thread(target=ProgressBarLoop, args=(self, bar))
      t.start()
root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When asking questions about Tkinter or Tk behavior in general, you should include exactly what version of Tk and on what platform you are using it as the behavior of Tk varies by platform and version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your own binding to manage the visibility of the overrideredirect-ed window. Tkinter generates the events `<Map>` and `<UnMap>` when a widget is iconified or un-iconified. So, add bindings to the main window to call either `wm_deiconify` or `withdraw` on the popup window.